# Object Caching using C# in CRM Online

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365

I am using Object Caching in C# to store an EntityCollection in Cache.

Following is the code for caching :

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
const string keyName = "BrandPartners";
EntityCollection result;

if (!cache.Contains(keyName))
{
    result = GetCustomerData(service, firstName, lastName, gender);
    var cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy()
    {
        AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
    };

    tracingService.Trace("Writing into the cache");
    cache.Add(keyName, result, cacheItemPolicy);
}
else
{
    result = (EntityCollection)cache.Get(keyName);
    tracingService.Trace("Data already found in the cache");
}
```

So, when I am first creating a record in an entity in an instance in CRM online, I am getting the trace  : "Writing into the cache."

But, when I am again creating a record in the same entity, I am again getting the same trace ("Writing into the cache"). But, if I am using caching, I should not get this trace because the keyName of "BrandPartners" already exist in the cache.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How much time is between the two creating-actions? Because your cache expires after 5 minutes because of your `CacheItemPolicy`.

Comment: Where is the code being executed?

Comment: @JamesWood, it is a custom workflow. Hence, I am executing it as a step in a workflow.

Comment: Between two creating actions, the time is 1 minute. I gave the timer as 5 minutes just for the testing purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possible reasons why you're not seeing a cached value being found:

- You're on CRM online, or on-prem and have load balancing in place.  The Memory Cache is obviously only for a single process on a single machine.
- The Workflow activity is registered for multiple workflows/entities, in sandbox mode.  In this case, each and every instance of the registration would get a separate sandbox process, and therefore would have separate Memory Caches
- CRM decided to refresh the plugin sandbox process.  This happens from time to time to avoid memory leaks, so this may be the case as well.

Comment: Do we have a solution for this?

Comment: @RichaTibrewal which potential case applies to you?

Comment: I am on CRM online.

Comment: @Richa Tibrewal there will be some instances where the memory cache is used, but alot where it won't be.  I'm not sure there is a solution besides using something like Redis...